# appengine queries

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from google.appengine.ext import db

class ligas(models.Model):
    llave = models.TextField()
    liga = models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
from google.appengine.ext import db
from models import ligas

def liga(request, offset):
    dt = get_url(offset)
    html = "<html><body>la liga para %s es %s</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
    return HttpResponse(html)

def get_url(valor):
    direc = ''
    q = ligas.objects.all()
    q.filter("llave=", valor)
    direc = q.get()
    return direc.liga
```

I am new using django with google app engine. I cant query the db. Im getting this error:

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: too many values to unpack
```

making a query directly in the shell I get this:

```
>>> uno = ligas.objects.all()[0]
>>> uno.liga
u'www.yahoo.com'
>>> uno.llave
u'yahoo'
```

I cant figure out what I get wrong.
any help please.

```
traceback:
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/sake/as/

Django Version: 1.3.7
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'djangotoolbox',
 'autoload',
 'dbindexer',
 'polls',
 'djangoappengine']
Installed Middleware:
('autoload.middleware.AutoloadMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/alex_gmoca/kl-panel/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/alex_gmoca/kl-panel/sake/views.py" in liga
  6.     dt = get_url(offset)
File "/Users/alex_gmoca/kl-panel/sake/views.py" in get_url
  13.   q.filter("llave=", "as")
File "/Users/alex_gmoca/kl-panel/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  552.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/alex_gmoca/kl-panel/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  570.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/Users/alex_gmoca/kl-panel/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1192.                             can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
File "/Users/alex_gmoca/kl-panel/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_filter
  1022.         arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: ValueError at /sake/as/
Exception Value: too many values to unpack
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, please post the entire traceback, not only the last line. This will help others help you!

Comment: Are you using cloud sql?

Answer (score 1):

This

```
q.filter("llave=", valor)
```

should be

```
q.filter(llave=valor)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups-intro) for more info